# In James Blish's "Jack of Eagles", how is "Danny Caiden" a corruption of a New Orleans term, and what has it to do with movies?

Tags: james-blish

In James Blish's book *Jack of Eagles*, there is this dialogue:

> "Shut the door, Tooey. So you're Danny Caiden. Your mother must of
> hung too much around the movies."
>
> "The name's a corruption of a New Orleans term that would be familiar
> to anybody with two brain cells," Danny said evenly.

What New Orleans term is the name a corruption of, and what does the first speaker think it has to do with movies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Likely this was a reference to Oscar and Golden-Globe winning actor [Danny Kaye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Kaye), who was very popular in the 1940s and 1950s. If his mother had been hanging around the movies, she would certainly have seen him in some of the biggest films of the day, including *White Christmas*, *The Secret Life of Walter Mitty* and *The Court Jester*.

The "corruption" of the surname is almost certainly **Caiden = [Acadien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acadians)**, a term that would be instantly familiar to New Orleanians.

Comment: More like a corruption of [Acadian.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acadians)  "Cajun" itself is a corrupt form of Acadian.  Caiden would derive from Acadian rather than "Cajun."

Comment: @JRE - You're not wrong.